# Left joining 2 of the same table with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am trying to combine 2 results from the table using the following SQL:

```
select * (
  SELECT Datepart(mm,starttime) as Month, COUNT(*) TotalCountSub
  from data 
  where usertype='subscriber'
  group by Datepart(mm,starttime)
  having count(*) > 1
 ) a
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Datepart(mm,starttime) as Month, COUNT(*) TotalCountCust
   from data
   where usertype='Customer'
   group by Datepart(mm,starttime)
   having count(*) > 1
 ) b on a.Month = b.Month
order by Datepart(mm,starttime) ASC
```

What i am trying to achieve here is to combine both results into 1 table:

Table1

```
Month|TotalCountSub
1    |50
2    |123
3    |14
4    |91
```

Table2

```
Month|TotalCountCust
1    |80
2    |465
3    |79
4    |84
```

Results should be:

```
Month|TotalCountSub|TotalCountCust
1    |50           |80
2    |123          |465
3    |14           |79
4    |91           |84
```

Comment: Can you post a sample set of rows from the `data` table? I suspect this is simpler than your two subqueries make it appear.

Comment: I think i just solved it myself.
SELECT
      Datepart(mm,starttime),
      COUNT(CASE WHEN usertype='Subscriber' THEN 1 END) count_type_1,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN usertype='Customer'  THEN 1 END) count_type_2,
  
    FROM
      Data
    GROUP BY
  Datepart(mm,starttime)

Comment: Yes, that's probably the simplest method. You can post your own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works:

```
select a.Month, a.TotalCountSub, b.TotalCountCust from (
  SELECT Datepart(mm,starttime) as Month, COUNT(*) TotalCountSub
  from data 
  where usertype='subscriber'
  group by Datepart(mm,starttime)
  having count(*) > 1
 ) a
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Datepart(mm,starttime) as Month, COUNT(*) TotalCountCust
   from data
   where usertype='Customer'
   group by Datepart(mm,starttime)
   having count(*) > 1
 ) b 
ON a.Month = b.Month
order by a.Month ASC
```